# reCaptcha ERROR: Invalid domain for site key in Google Server

Tags: recaptcha

i get recaptcha, put my   domain.com.ar and get a key

i use this code

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {

 var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
 return t.evaluate().setTitle("Contacto de Usuarios").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}


function processForm(formObject) {


 var userCompleto = formObject.userCompleto;

 var Email = formObject.Email;

 var Movil = formObject.Movil;

 var Mensaje = formObject.Mensaje

 var captcha = formObject.g-recaptcha-response

 var captcha1 = formObject.g-recaptcha


 Logger.log(userCompleto+Email+Movil+captcha)

  //etc code ........


  }
```

Index.htm

```
  <form id="myForm2" action="?" method="post" >


  <input type="text" name="userCompleto" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="userCompleto" size="30"> 

  <input type="text" name="Email" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="Email" size="30"> 

   <input type="text" name="Movil" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="Movil" size="30"> 


   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Mensaje" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="Mensaje" size="30" >

   <div id= "example2"></div>

   <input type="button" value="Comunicate" id="comunica" name="comunica" style="height: 30px" onclick="validateForm2()" />


   </form>
   <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

JavaScript.htm

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


  var onloadCallback = function() {

  var widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('example2'), {
      'sitekey' : '6LeDlhUTAAAAAMbdjlTLHDzA8MMb_pQS6epqgLHs'
    });

  };

 </script>


 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
 </script>



 <script type='text/javascript' >

  function  validateForm2(){

    //..validation 

   var objDatosGuardar = document.getElementById("myForm2")

     google.script.run.processForm2(objDatosGuardar);

   };


   </script>
```

trow a ERROR   ERROR: Invalid domain for site key

I try change de key for the captcha and nothing
I try to put in the key new domains like 127.0.0.0
I dont get Looger.log nothing

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a look of your environment and check if one of the cases below applies?

1. Someone seems like solve the same problem by deleting the existing key and reissuing the key.

[reCAPTCHA ERROR: Invalid domain for site key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735694/recaptcha-error-invalid-domain-for-site-key)

2. [Using reCAPTCHA on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost): This question below says that there is a possibility that you need to reissue, if you migrated from the V1 to V2.
3. And one of the comments in this question also suggests you may need to add a different name, not localhost.

I personally used reCaptcha and reCaptchaV2 and never came across this problem, and noticed that I always used a domain name specified by hosts file(/etc/hosts) even if it run in my localhost.