# Google reCaptcha not working on bootstrap modal popup

Tags: bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

Hi i have added the google reCaptcha in the bootstrap modal i am using same key on the index page and on the modal which opens after button click on the index ,on page it is working fine but on modal popup it is showing error "ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key"

I have added the screenshot
[image: Model Popup Image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reCAPTCHA ERROR: Invalid domain for site key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735694/recaptcha-error-invalid-domain-for-site-key)

Comment: no this one is different, i am getting this on modal popup on same page

Comment: Hi I got the same bug do you found the solution to this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enqueue recaptcha script or add it to the footer like this

```
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?;ver=2.0′></script>
```