# Recaptcha code is failing on website created using Google sites

Tags: recaptcha, google-sites

I have tried to use the recpatcha V2, check box on my Google Site - https://www.filmwrench.com/ , using the embed element.

I have used the code snippet provided here - [Automatically render the reCAPTCHA widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render) . The same code works fine on a wordpress website

Here is the recaptcha key for my website
[image: Key-Site combination]

So why is the recpatcha failing? Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured the solution to the same is - [Uncheck the DNS Validation in ReCaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284094/10054727) . Not sure, this is only required for Google sites. But it does it.

Thanks